# ExpressionEngine {exp:channel:categories}, categories from multiple category groups ordered together

Tags: channel-entries, categories

Is it possible to create a single alphabetically ordered list containing categories from *multiple* category groups?

Here is the code I am using:

```
<ul>
    {exp:channel:categories category_group="1|2"}
         <li>{category_name}</li>
    {/exp:channel:categories}
</ul>
```

Unfortunately this separates the category groups, and I end up with a list such as this:

- book
- graphic identity
- poster
- website
- architecture
- art
- David Bowie
- ExpressionEngine
- zoos

You'll notice that it is actually two lists ordered alphabetically. I would like to merge these into one list somehow.

I would expect to be able to add something like `orderby=` as in the [Channel Entries Tag](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#orderby):

```
<ul>
    {exp:channel:categories category_group="1|2" orderby="name"}
         <li>{category_name}</li>
    {/exp:channel:categories}
</ul>
```

But this does not work. Has anyone come across this before?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[GWcode Categories](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories) may be more helpful to you.
You can do a whole lot more with categories than the native solution.

I would be very surprised if it couldn't do what you need.

**OR**
Use [Stash](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash).

Get *all* the categories you need, don't worry about the order.
Once they are stashed, they become one single list.

```
{exp:stash:set_list name="categories" parse_tags="yes"}
  {exp:channel:categories category_group="1|2"}
    {stash:name}{category_name}{/stash:name}
  {/exp:channel:categories}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

Then just output them all in the order you need.

```
<ul>
{exp:stash:get_list name="categories" orderby="name"}
  <li>{name}</li>
{/exp:stash:get_list}
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your answer. I'll look into those options. I take it there is not a way to do this without using any add ons then?

Comment: I can't say for sure... But, I would have tried the same code as you did, and it appears not to work.